# Effective way to check list, without using a variable as an index counter - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Hi I were wondering if there were a better way or a more pythonic way to check the contents of a list without using a variable. 
Normally I use more than one index counter and it looks messy.

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
list2 = ['foo', 'bundy', 'baz']
i = 0
for x in range(0,3):
    if list1[i] in list2[i]:
        print('In list')
    else:
        print('Not in list')
    i +=1
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your code is trying to achieve. (For example, what's your intent with `list1[i] in list2[i]`?)

Comment: Finding out whether or not list2 contains the values from list1. Then if i can avoid using a variable as a counter. In this code that would be "i".

Comment: But why don't you just use `x`?

Comment: Because i didn't know i could do that, until now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What should your code do? What would be the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

To check whether elements of 1 list are present in other list or not. You can convert them into sets and use intersection and symmetric difference like this:

```
>>> list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> list2 = ['foo', 'bundy', 'baz']
>>> set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
{'foo', 'baz'}
>>> set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2))
{'bar', 'bundy'}
>>> set(list1).difference(set(list2))
{'bar'}
>>> set(list2).difference(set(list1))
{'bundy'}
>>>
```

Intersection gives you common elements between the 2 sets.

[image]

Difference gives you elements present in 1 set with respect to another.

[image]

[image]

Symmetric difference gives you uncommon elements from both sets.

[image]

Comment: It is not easy to understand for a beginner.

Comment: Added a bit of explanation

Comment: OP is doing `if list1[i] in list2[i]`, not `if list1[i] in list2`. (Might be an error in OP's code, though...)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can write it this way:

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
list2 = ['foo', 'bundy', 'baz']
for element in list1:
    if element in list2:
        print('In list')
    else:
        print('Not in list')
```

Good luck!

Comment: Also, if you are just interested in the shared elements of two lists use set(). `in_both_lists = set(list1) & set(list2)`

Comment: OP is doing `if list1[i] in list2[i]`, not `if list1[i] in list2`. (Might be an error in OP's code, though...)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. I *think* your goal is to see whether each element in the first list is contained in the corresponding element in list 2, but I'm not certain.

Secondly, I don't understand why you have two counter variables, `x` and `i`. They both do the same jobs; you should remove `i` altogether and just use `x`, which is incremented automatically by the for loop.

However, the really Pythonic thing to do is not to use counters at all. You should zip the two lists together and iterate over the resulting list of tuples:

```
for elem1, elem2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if elem1 in elem2:
```